# Changing the direction of a particle in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a particle the explodes upwards. This would work the way I want if the particle always hit the ground. However I want the particle to explode at a -90 degree angle if it hits a wall from the left to look like you just exploded the wall. Is there a way to rotate the particle emitter in any way? Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the emitter angle by modifying the `ScaledNumericValue` that represents the angle of the `ParticleEmitter`.

Given some target angle, you can read the angle information from the `ParticleEmitter` and adjust its high and low boundries accordingly.

A quick solution might look something like this;

```
ParticleEffect effect = /* your effect */
ParticleEmitter emitter = effect.findEmitter("some_name"); // find the emitter you want to     rotate here
float targetAngle = /* your target angle */

ScaledNumericValue angle = emitter.getAngle();

/* find angle property and adjust that by letting the min, max of low and high span their current size around your angle */

float angleHighMin = angle.getHighMin();
float angleHighMax = angle.getHighMax();
float spanHigh = angleHighMax - angleHighMin;
angle.setHigh(angle - spanHigh / 2.0f, angle + spanHigh / 2.0f);

float angleLowMin = angle.getLowhMin();
float angleLowMax = angle.getLowMax();
float spanLow = angleLowMax - angleLowMin;
angle.setLow(angle - spanLow / 2.0f, angle + spanLow / 2.0f);
```